# AWS mobile hub nosql

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, pgadmin, amazon-mobile-hub

In AWS mobile hub nosql, is there any chance for me to connect through pgadmin or web browser so that I can import bulk data to the nosql database. Thanks.

Comment: This question seems to be more suitable for [su], as it does not have anything to do with programming directly.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL tables created by AWS Mobile Hub are managed by Amazon DynamoDB ([What Is Amazon DynamoDB?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html)). I recommend using this guide to import data:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html

To find the Amazon DynamoDB table associated with your AWS Mobile Hub project, simply go to your mobile hub project homepage, click on "Resources" located on the top-right corner. You will see a list of AWS Resources in your mobile hub project.

You can also read: [How to import bulk data from csv to dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678325/how-to-import-bulk-data-from-csv-to-dynamodb)

Comment: Your links to the documentation are incomplete, I fixed the first one, but could not determine the correct URL for the second for the import data.